# Why is the horizontal layout overflowing on wider resolution phones but fitting on skinnier phones

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an app that has a horizontal row of image buttons, but I discovered that when I run it on my LG G6 (physical), which is a skinny phone, then the image buttons go off screen to the side. The resolution is 2880 x 1440, which is 18:9 ratio.

Now I expected my layout to be incorrect for other phones that are skinnier and have a taller ratio like the pixel 3a but in the android studio preview the horizontal layout fits perfectly on it. The resolution on the 3a is also lower at 2,220 x 1,080 and taller at 18.5:9.

But how come the images in my row is overflowing on my LG G6 but not the 3A?? Does it change when I run my app on a physical device vs. an emulator on android studio?? It doesn't make sense to me because there's less pixels width-wise on the 3a but everything is fitting when it doesn't on the G6.

Thanks!

edit: This is my layout, it's basically an image button in the center of a constraint layout, and there's supposed to be another image button beside it on the right, but it isn't in the constraint layout.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/horizontalLayoutBottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalLayoutTop">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/centerPiece"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/centerPiece" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> 

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightPiece"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="260dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputText"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rightPiece" />
```

This is what it's looking like on my G6: [image]

And this is what android studio is telling me it should look like: [image]

Comment: It would be great if you could post your layout so that we could take a look in that as well. Thank you!

Comment: @ReazMurshed Just made an edit!